# MATLAB Compiler getting stuck during build process

Tags: matlab, mcc

I built a GUI in MATLAB that makes use of the Instrument Control Toolbox, among other things. I tried to compile this GUI with `deploytool` but it's getting stuck during the compile:

```
ant:

<mkdir dir="Z:\My Path\MyApp\distrib" />
<mkdir dir="Z:\My Path\MyApp\src" />
mcc -o MyApp -W WinMain:MyApp -T link:exe -d 'Z:\My Path\MyApp\src' -N -p instrument -w enable:specified_file_mismatch -w enable:repeated_file -w enable:switch_ignored -w enable:missing_lib_sentinel -w enable:demo_license -v 'Z:\My Path\MyApp.m'

Compiler version: 4.18.1 (R2013a)   
Processing C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\matlab\mcc.enc
Processing C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\instrument\mcc.enc
Processing C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\shared\instrument\mcc.enc
Processing include files...
2 item(s) added.
Processing directories installed with MCR...
The file Z:\My Path\MyApp\src\mccExcludedFiles.log contains a list of functions excluded from the CTF archive.
0 item(s) added.
Generating MATLAB path for the compiled application...
Created 54 path items.
```

And that's all she wrote. Of note, the final statement of "Created 54 path items" to me doesn't make a whole lot of sense, since I don't have 54 dependencies.

I changed the path that the code is on to `Z:\My Path\MyApp` to be generic. It may or may not be important but there are spaces in the path. I mentioned this because maybe that's my problem. Z:\ is a network drive instead of a local drive. Some dependencies live on R:\, which is also a network drive. All dependencies are on the MATLAB path or in my local folder.

I'm using MATLAB R2013a x64 and the Windows SDK 7.1 (used `mbuild -setup` to set this).

The `deploytool` and MATLAB are both responsive - I can cancel the build process with no problem. I ran the `mcc` code verbatim as above and it's still stuck in the same place with no indication that it's working. Hitting CTRL-C to interrupt it gives no error messages or anything.

Does anyone know what's going on? It must be something to do with the `mcc` call, I'm sure of it.

Comment: It worked! It just took a **REALLY** long time and gave no visible indication that it was doing anything. I still would love to know what is taking this thing so long. The verbose output isn't really very verbose. I'm going to leave this instead of delete so others who stumble into this situation can rest easy knowing that something is actually happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this problem is due to my license file being located on a network server rather than locally. Working with MathWorks tech support really helped out here.

When using `mcc`, specify a local license file with the `-Y` flag. The compile then goes from 20 minutes or so to about 2. An example call:

```
mcc -m -v -N -Y alpha.lic myApp.m
```